# Monggose array schema type not passing more than one items

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I am trying to pass an array of schemas that will populate multiple social media documents in the qrCode document but when I send the post request using Postman it only sends 1 of them.

This is the QrCode Modle where the shcema is being defined

```
const Joi = require("joi");
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const { themeSchema } = require("./Theme");
const { userSchema } = require("./User");
const { socialSchema } = require("./Social");

const QrCode = mongoose.model(
  "QrCode",
  new mongoose.Schema({
    user: {
      type: userSchema,
      required: true,
    },
    name: {
      type: String,
      maxLength: 255,
      required: true,
      trim: true,
    },
    theme: {
      type: themeSchema,
      required: true,
    },
    // Social Media Links
    social: [
      {
        type: socialSchema,
        required: true,
      },
    ],
  })
);

function ValidateQrCode(qrCode) {
  const schema = {
    userId: Joi.objectId(),
    name: Joi.string().max(255).required(),
    themeId: Joi.objectId().required(),
    socialId: Joi.array().required().items(Joi.string()),
  };

  return Joi.validate(qrCode, schema);
}

module.exports.QrCode = QrCode;
module.exports.validate = ValidateQrCode;
```

This is the post route to create a new qrCode

```
const { QrCode, validate } = require("../models/QrCode");
const { Theme } = require("../models/Theme");
const { User } = require("../models/User");
const { Social } = require("../models/Social");
const auth = require("../middleware/auth");
const express = require("express");
const router = express.Router();

router.get("/", async (req, res) => {
  const qrCodes = await QrCode.find().sort("-name");
  res.send(qrCodes);
});

router.post("/", auth, async (req, res) => {
  const { error } = validate(req.body);
  if (error) res.status(400).send(error.details[0].message);

  const theme = await Theme.findById(req.body.themeId);
  if (!theme) return res.status(400).send("Invalid theme.");

  const social = await Social.findById(req.body.socialId);
  if (!social) return res.status(400).send("Invalid social.");

  const user = await User.findById(req.user._id);
  if (!user) return res.status(400).send("Invalid theme.");

  const qrCode = new QrCode({
    user: user,
    name: req.body.name,
    theme: theme,
    social: social,
  });

  await qrCode.save();

  res.send(qrCode);
});

module.exports = router;
```

This is the postman post request that I send

```
{
    "name": "Test399",
    "themeId": "60f607ab97943dfaa05811bc",
    //the ID's for all the socials
    "socialId": ["60f657f97f90bb0cd10cfef1", "60f77d179b05d91894ef32ab"]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your route has

```js
const social = await Social.findById(req.body.socialId);
```

here you are trying to pass array and [Mongoose findById](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.findById) document says to send the _id for query, that is the reason mongoose gives only one value.

Iterate over the array and get values before sending the response.